# SQL table transform

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have Table A

```
customerID  Product
-------------------
 101            A
 101            B
 102            B
 102            C
```

Want to transform it to a Table B like:

```
customerID  ProductA ProductB ProductC
---------------------------------------
 101             1        1        0
 102             0        1        1
```

My ultimate goal is to leverage this intermediate table to get Table C like this:

```
customerID   Product_Combo
--------------------------
 101              AB
 102              BC
```

I think I know how to change it from B to C. But how to go from A to B? Thanks! Suppose we do this in MS SQL and we only have three products A,B, and C.

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  In addition, you might want a more representative set of data.  Are there always at most two products?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way would be to use case :

```
SELECT custId
,MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'A' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS productA
,MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS productB
,MAX(CASE WHEN product = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS productC
 FROM A 
Group by  custId
```

Result

```
custId  productA    productB    productC
 101    1             1           0
 102    0             1           1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cursor for customerId and this sql:

```
declare @Products varchar(10) = '';

--start cursor
set @Products = '';
SELECT @Products = @Products + [Product] 
  FROM [test].[dbo].[TableA]
  WHERE customerId = @cursor

print @Products
--end cursor
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use query like this to get into B

```
SELECT
    CustomerId,
    CASE
        WHEN [A] = 'A' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS ProductA,
    CASE
        WHEN [B] = 'B' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS ProductB,
    CASE
        WHEN [C] = 'C' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
    END AS ProductC
FROM #tableA
PIVOT (MAX(Product) FOR Product IN ([A], [B], [C])) AS p
```